# Summing frequency based on timestamp interval

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe that contains timestamps and counter columns. The timestamps are spread apart by 1 min intervals. The counter indicates the number of events occurring at the timestamp.
At every timestamp, **I want to calculate the number of events in the next ten minutes**. So at timestamp 2018-01-03 00:00:00, the no of events would be 3.

I created a function to which I pass each row of the dataframe and it retruns the no of events in the next 10 mins. I am getting the right answer but the runtime is very high and I would like a faster way to do this because I intend to run this on a large dataset. I think this can be achieved quickly with an efficient use of groupby and transform but I am not sure how to do ti. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
a = pd.DataFrame()
a['timestamp'] = pd.date_range('2018-01-03 00:00:00', '2018-01-03 00:20:00', freq='01min').to_list()
a['counter'] = 0
a['counter'][5] = 2
a['counter'][7]= 1
a['counter'][16] = 3
```

The dataframe looks like:

```
           timestamp    counter
0   2018-01-03 00:00:00 0
1   2018-01-03 00:01:00 0
2   2018-01-03 00:02:00 0
3   2018-01-03 00:03:00 0
4   2018-01-03 00:04:00 0
5   2018-01-03 00:05:00 2
6   2018-01-03 00:06:00 0
7   2018-01-03 00:07:00 1
8   2018-01-03 00:08:00 0
9   2018-01-03 00:09:00 0
10  2018-01-03 00:10:00 0
11  2018-01-03 00:11:00 0
12  2018-01-03 00:12:00 0
13  2018-01-03 00:13:00 0
14  2018-01-03 00:14:00 0
15  2018-01-03 00:15:00 0
16  2018-01-03 00:16:00 3
17  2018-01-03 00:17:00 0
18  2018-01-03 00:18:00 0
19  2018-01-03 00:19:00 0
20  2018-01-03 00:20:00 0
```

I apply the following function to each row of the df, which calculates number of events in next 10 mins

```
def count_events(a, time_diff):
    temp_df = a[(a['timestamp'] > time_diff)& (a['timestamp'] <=(time_diff + pd.Timedelta(minutes=10)))]
    events = sum(temp_df['counter'])
    return events


for i in range(len(a)):
    a['no_of_events'][i] = count_events(a, a['timestamp'][i])
```

The output is (this is the correct output):

```
      timestamp     counter no_of_events
0   2018-01-03 00:00:00 0   3
1   2018-01-03 00:01:00 0   3
2   2018-01-03 00:02:00 0   3
3   2018-01-03 00:03:00 0   3
4   2018-01-03 00:04:00 0   3
5   2018-01-03 00:05:00 2   1
6   2018-01-03 00:06:00 0   4
7   2018-01-03 00:07:00 1   3
8   2018-01-03 00:08:00 0   3
9   2018-01-03 00:09:00 0   3
10  2018-01-03 00:10:00 0   3
11  2018-01-03 00:11:00 0   3
12  2018-01-03 00:12:00 0   3
13  2018-01-03 00:13:00 0   3
14  2018-01-03 00:14:00 0   3
15  2018-01-03 00:15:00 0   3
16  2018-01-03 00:16:00 3   0
17  2018-01-03 00:17:00 0   0
18  2018-01-03 00:18:00 0   0
19  2018-01-03 00:19:00 0   0
20  2018-01-03 00:20:00 0   0
```

Comment: I dont think your output is correct. Why is no_of_events in row 5, 1 and then in row 6 4?

Comment: What I think you want is: `a['no_of_events'] = a.rolling('10min', on='timestamp').sum()['counter']`

Comment: I am calculating the number of events in next 10 mins, so at min 5, it is 3-2 = 1.

Comment: The answer you suggested does that work. I think it gives the events that happened 10 min before. I am looking for 10 min after. Thanks for giving me a starting point though. I will try to look more into rolling.

Comment: I think what you want is: `a['no_of_events'] = a.rolling('10min', on='timestamp')['counter'].sum()[::-1].values`

Comment: Thanks, but this solution also doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As people suggested in the comments, [rolling](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) is the best way to do it. Seems that you want to roll forward starting from the line, but `rolling` do a backward roll. You can solve this inverting the rows of your dataframe using `.iloc[::-1]` and use it again after the rolling operation to put them back in the right order.

```
b = a.iloc[::-1].rolling(10, on='timestamp', min_periods=1).sum().iloc[::-1]
```

`b` is:

```
             timestamp  counter
0  2018-01-03 00:00:00      3.0
1  2018-01-03 00:01:00      3.0
2  2018-01-03 00:02:00      3.0
3  2018-01-03 00:03:00      3.0
4  2018-01-03 00:04:00      3.0
5  2018-01-03 00:05:00      3.0
6  2018-01-03 00:06:00      1.0
7  2018-01-03 00:07:00      4.0
8  2018-01-03 00:08:00      3.0
9  2018-01-03 00:09:00      3.0
10 2018-01-03 00:10:00      3.0
11 2018-01-03 00:11:00      3.0
12 2018-01-03 00:12:00      3.0
13 2018-01-03 00:13:00      3.0
14 2018-01-03 00:14:00      3.0
15 2018-01-03 00:15:00      3.0
16 2018-01-03 00:16:00      3.0
17 2018-01-03 00:17:00      0.0
18 2018-01-03 00:18:00      0.0
19 2018-01-03 00:19:00      0.0
20 2018-01-03 00:20:00      0.0
```

#### EDIT

To exclude the current timestamp, you can use [shift](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) to shift the counter column by 1 position. Just do:

```
a['counter'] = a['counter'].shift(-1)
```

before using `rolling`.

Comment: Thank you. That works! It calculates the events happening at that timestamp as well, but I am good with that.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that you want to exclude the current timestamp. To do that, you can use `pandas.shift` before. Let me just edit the answer